# ActionBar con flecha en un MapsActivity

Tags: android, actionbar

Como puedo poner un ActionBar con una flecha de retroceder en una MapsActivity que extiende de FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu Activity extiende de `AppCompatActivity` puedes usar :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
...

      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

que da como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de que tu `Activity` extienda de `FragmentActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

La opción es agregar un Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

y asignarle la flecha :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

y obtener algo similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo este [sitio](https://material.io/icons/#ic_arrow_back) para obtener iconos "material design".

Comment: Ya lo intente de esa manera pero me marca error aqui: getSupportActionBar(), este es el código que tengo:

[ public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final float ZOOM_BY = 0.5f;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); ]

Comment: ok ahora veo tu Activity es : MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity , el import de FragmentActivity es: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; ?

Comment: si así es: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Comment: @KikeHatake si tu _minSDKVersion_ es 11 o mayor usa `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: Si lo intento con getActionBar(); no marca error, pero al momento de abrir el activity de mi mapas se cierra mi aplicacion @x4mp73r

Comment: @KikeHatake si extiende de FragmentActivity agregué la opción con un Toolbar. Si extiende de FragmentActivity  no se puede usar getActionBar();